# how do I print only the symbolically linked directories?

Tags: command-line, directory, find, symlink, file-type

Using the **find** command,  I can pass the flag **-type** to print only files of a certain type.
For example, to print only directories in the current directory, I run:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d
```

---

These are the other types:

```
-type c
File is of type c:

b        block (buffered) special

c        character (unbuffered) special

d        directory

p        named pipe (FIFO)

f        regular file

l        symbolic link; this is never true if the -L option or the
         -follow  option is in effect, unless the symbolic link is
         broken.  If you want to search for symbolic links when -L
         is in effect, use -xtype.

s        socket

D        door (Solaris)
```

The problem is that a symbolically linked directory is not considered a directory of **-type d**, and the flag for symbolic links(**-type l**) is to broad because it will also include symbolically linked files that aren't directories. Perhaps a symbolic file is treated the same whether it points to a directory or file, but how would I ensure I only print the ones that point to directories?  I don't necessarily have to use the **find** command.

Comment: what OS is this? Linux?

Comment: @JoeDF Linux (Ubuntu)

Comment: does this work? `find -L -xtype l -type d`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try :** `find -L -xtype l -type d`